# Gramaticas y Parsing

Tags: parser, gramatica-libre-de-contexto

Tengo un problema con la siguiente pregunta de tarea, no entiendo como exactamente como realizar lo siguiente, les agradeceria mucha la ayuda.

Considere la siguiente gramática, donde A, B y C son los no terminales

```
A → uA | wuA | B + B | ∊

B → bB | CB | ∊

C → cAw
```

Construya los conjuntos First para los no terminales.

Construya los conjuntos Follow para los no terminales.

Construya la tabla de parsing LL(1).

Muestre la secuencia de aplicación de la tabla de parsing LL(1) para la cadena de entrada “cuw+b”. Debe reportar en cada paso el estado de “Stack”, “Input” y “Action”, empezando con la pila conteniendo solamente A$ al inicio del proceso.

Comment: Considera leer [ask] y agregar lo que lleves

Comment: @Maximuz: Por favor ¿Podrías dar alguna referencia teórica para que podamos entender tu pregunta?